How to make browsers like Chrome and Firefox display the PDF file name in tab title for file created with Printing to PDF in Publisher?
When using Publisher, for certain reasons, I choose Print to create PDF, not Export to PDF.
After printing to PDF and opening the resulting PDF in Chrome or Firefox, the tab title displays the source file's name including the extension ".pub".

And I don't like that because the end users who read the PDF have nothing to do with the source file's name. I would rather like the tab to show the pdf file name:

I use Microsoft Print to PDF printer, but the same result I get with PDF24.
Earlier when I used Export, the tab in Chrome or Firefox displayed the PDF file name exactly as I needed.
Microsoft Edge displays the PDF file name in tab as needed no matter I print to PDF or Export to PDF.
I can't find any setting like Name to be adjusted in the Print options.
How to make browsers like Chrome and Firefox display the PDF file name in tab title for file created with Printing to PDF in Publisher?

Is there a particular reason that you are using "Print to PDF" instead of Export? I would guess this is a function of there being more than one field that may contain the document Title in a PDF, and that applications that display PDFs can choose which of these to pick from, and that the Print to PDF function does not write to the fields Chrome and Firefox expect. Regardless, the simplest method is the one you have control over: the way you create the PDF. Other methods will require you to modify likely hidden browser settings, or manually edit the metadata fields of the file.

@music2myear Yes, I started getting a problem with exporting to pdf a couple of months ago. And the workaround described on the Microsoft forum thread doesn't help. That's why I switched to Printing. Manually adding the metadata fields may be an option, I'll check that, thanks

@music2myear yes, editing metadata works for me. You may post it as an answer, I will support it

The most consistent way to resolve this is to edit the PDFs metadata. There are a variety of tools you can do this using. PDFtk seems to be well regarded and has a free version: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/
I cannot find a document noting which fields need to be modified in order to display the correct title, but I'd guess if you Export a PDF and use the Print To PDF function, and compare the two files, it'll be easy enough to identify the value that the tabs are using to display.
